# In azure IoT Hub sending more than 256KB Device-to-cloud message did not throw any error as per documentation. How?

Tags: node.js, .net, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am sending a Telemetry of around 720 KB from a registered device which is more than Maximum message size allowed for Device-to-cloud messaging as per below documentation.

It's sent using  IoT Hub nodejs sdk provided by Microsoft

[MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling#other-limits)

It's mentioned as below in the document

*Device-to-cloud messaging :
Maximum message size 256 KB*

Then what is this limit? Did my understanding is wrong?

I measure the Byte Count and log it before sending to find out the size.

Answer (score 1):

[See Azure IoT C# SDK throws error message beyond 256KB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJCTV.png)
I guess your assumption of 720 KB is wrong, check my screenshot and the code where I'm batching my data up to a size of 500 + KB and device SDK found the message is beyond the allowed limit.

```
// Async method to send simulated telemetry
    private static async Task SendDeviceToCloudMessagesAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        // Initial telemetry values
        double minTemperature = 20;
        double minHumidity = 60;
        var rand = new Random();

        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            double currentTemperature = minTemperature + rand.NextDouble() * 15;
            double currentHumidity = minHumidity + rand.NextDouble() * 20;

            JArray a = new JArray();

            string messageBody = null;
            bool messageSize = true;
            // Create JSON message
            while (messageSize)
            {
                messageBody = JsonSerializer.Serialize(
                    new
                    {
                        temperature = currentTemperature,
                        humidity = currentHumidity,
                        vibration = rand.NextDouble() * 15,
                        moisture = rand.NextDouble() * 15,
                        O2 = rand.NextDouble() * 15
                    });
                // messageCollectionBody = messageCollectionBody + messageBody + ",";
                a.Add(messageBody);
                int msgSize = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Unicode.GetByteCount(a.ToString());
                if (msgSize >= 556000)   // set anything above 270 KB to observe the error!
                {
                    messageSize = false;
                }
            }

            using var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(a.ToString()))
            {
                ContentType = "application/json",
                ContentEncoding = "utf-8",
            };

            // Add a custom application property to the message.
            // An IoT hub can filter on these properties without access to the message body.
            message.Properties.Add("temperatureAlert", (currentTemperature > 30) ? "true" : "false");

            // Send the telemetry message
            await s_deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} > Sending message: {a.ToString()}");

            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```